# Reading from ContentProvider while performing bulkInsert()

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-contentprovider

In my application I have a lot of data to download, parse and insert into DB during the run. The data is split into 3 parts.
I don't want users to wait too long and let them use app after parsing first part, and have parser working in the background. 
I have custom ContentProvider and using the bulkInsert method to insert data. Parser works in separate thread (IntentService).
The problem is reading and writing data from ContentProvider simultaneously doesn't work well,
ListViews (using Cursor) scrolling is not smooth. 
Any ideas how to improve performance in this case? Maybe I should use second, temporary database for the first part?

Comment: Same case for me , i'm trying to parsing a huge set of data from a json response in IntentService ..and trying to insert data in db . this make UI freeze some times.

i m trying to use SyncService and see the difference, but i m opinion it s the same thinks.